# remove missing values from dataframe and reshape the dataframe with the non-missing ones

Tags: r, dataframe, nan, reshape2

I have a dataframe that has missing values at each column, but at different rows. For simplicity, let's see the following dataframe (real dataframe is much more complex):

```
first_column <- c(1, 2, NA,NA)
second_column <- c(NA, NA, 4,9)

df <- data.frame(first_column, second_column)
```

and we get:

```
  first_column second_column
1            1            NA
2            2            NA
3           NA             4
4           NA             9
```

Now, I want to reshape the dataframe, after removing these missing values. I want the following:

```
  first_column second_column
1            1            4
2            2            9
```

Is there an automatic way to do it (real dataframe has dimensions 1800 x 33)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may have to reorder the column values so that the `NA`s are at the end and then use `drop_na`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ .x[order(is.na(.x))])) %>% 
   drop_na()
```

-output

```
   first_column second_column
1            1             4
2            2             9
```

---

If there are unequal distribution of `NA`s in each column and wants to remove the row only if all the columns have NA at a particular row after ordering, use `if_all/if_all` in `filter`

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x[order(is.na(.x))])) %>%
   filter(if_any(everything(), complete.cases))
```

-output

```
  first_column second_column
1            1             4
2            2             9
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
df_new = as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]))

  first_column second_column
1            1             4
2            2             9
```